# How to apply CSS to top layer of unordered list anchor tags but not secondary?

Tags: css

So I have the following code:

```
<ul class="nav-items">
  <li class="menu-active nav-stuff"><a href='1'>One</a></li>
  <li class="menu-active nav-stuff"><a href='2'>Two</a></li>
     <ul>
       <li><a href='A'>A</a></li>
       <li><a href='B'>B</a></li>
       <li><a href='C'>C</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
  <li class="menu-active nav-stuff"><a href='3'>Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to apply a border specifically to One Two and Three but NOT A B and C. Right now I have:

```
.nav-items.menu-active a {
  color: green;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid orange;
 }
```

This works great for hitting One Two and Three but completely screws up as it also applies to A B and C. I've tried to do a:first-child but that's not working. Is there a way to hit only the upper li a?

EDIT: Fixed the nested unordered list and put in the right code for the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Direct Descendant/Child selector `>`

> The child combinator (>) is placed between two CSS selectors. It matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are the children of elements matched by the first.
>
> <sup>[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)</sup>

```
.nav-items > li.active > a
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-items>li.active>a {
  color: green;
  border-bottom: 5px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-items">
  <li class="menu active nav-stuff"><a href='1'>One</a></li>
  <li class="menu active nav-stuff"><a href='2'>Two</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='A'>A</a></li>
      <li><a href='B'>B</a></li>
      <li><a href='C'>C</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu active nav-stuff"><a href='3'>Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Also note that `padding-bottom: 5px solid orange;` is invalid CSS.

I have also corrected the HTML in that you had closed the `li` holding the submenu too soon.

Comment: Thanks for the fixes. I'll actually update the code. I missed a few items on typing it back up. I also spaced on using child combinator. It's just what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.nav-items.menu-active a {
  color: green;
  padding-bottom: 5px solid orange;
 }
.nav-items ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-items">
  <li class="menu active nav-stuff"><a href='1'>One</a></li>
  <li class="menu active nav-stuff"><a href='2'>Two</a></li>
     <ul>
       <li><a href='A'>A</a></li>
       <li><a href='B'>B</a></li>
       <li><a href='C'>C</a></li>
     </ul>
  <li class="menu active nav-stuff"><a href='3'>Three</a></li>
</ul>
```